# Limit Django's inlineformset_factory to only create new objects

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using django's inline formset factory. To use the example in the docs,

```
author = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book)
formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, instance=author)
```

will create an inline formset to edit books by a particular author.

I want to create a formset that only allows users to *add* new books by that author, not edit existing books. Is there a simple way to use inlineformset_factory to do this?

Answer (score 9):

inlineformset_factory takes a formset kwarg, which defaults to BaseInlineFormSet. BaseInlineFormSet subclasses BaseModelFormSet, which defines a get_queryset method. If you create a BaseInlineFormSet subclass and override get_queryset to return EmptyQuerySet(), you should get what you're after. In the above example then, it would look like this:

```
from django.db.models.query import EmptyQuerySet
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class BaseInlineAddOnlyFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return EmptyQuerySet()

author = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, formset=BaseInlineAddOnlyFormSet)
formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, instance=author)
```

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) appear to say that the preferred way to set the queryset is in overridden `__init__` after call to super.  But that isn't working for me.  Your method does, as does setting the kwarg `queryset` before call to super's `__init__`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Jeremy Lewis and if you don't want to subclass BaseInlineFormSet, you can just give an empty queryset parameter to your BookFormSet.

See pseudo (untested) Django 1.6 code sample:

```
BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(parent=Author, model=Book)
if request.method == "POST":
    formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=author)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
else:
    queryset = Book.objects.none() # does not allow to edit books
    formset = BookFormSet(instance=project, initial=initial, queryset=queryset)
return render(request, "add_book.html", { "formset": formset, })
```

Comment: inlineformset_factory now requires the 'fields' param to be explicitly specified. Just an update.

Comment: That is the solution for me! Thanks. Note: you need a queryset with a filter, something like `Book.objects.all()[0]` will not work. But this will:  `Book.objects.filter(pk=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is given in the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). Just don't give any instance to the FormSet. From the doc:

```
>>> from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
>>> BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book)
>>> author = Author.objects.get(name=u'Mike Royko')
>>> formset = BookFormSet() # This will create an empty form with your model fields
```

You can then create view as follows:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
else:
    formset = BookFormSet()
return render_to_response("add_book.html", {
    "formset": formset,
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't work for me; it still populates the formset with all `Book`s.  django 1.4.