# specify queryset when instantiating an inlineformset

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, inline-formset

I have the following in views.py to generate a page that shows an inline set of forms for a user's "qualifications"

```
from django.db.models import User
from models import UserQualification

def edit_quals(request):
    QualsFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, UserQualification, fields=('qualification', 'qualification_year', 'qualification_source'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = QualsFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = request.user)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

            #send user somewhere
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.user.get_profile_url())
    else:
        formset = QualsFormSet(instance = request.user)

    return render_to_response("edit_quals.html", {
        "formset": formset,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This works fine, however, I would like to create a `formset` that only includes certain 'UserQualification' objects (ie, only ones that are marked as a certain type) so when a user gets to this page they are only editing a subset of their qualifications. This reference seems to be what I want: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset. It deals with modelformset_factory, however inlineformset_factory is based on the prior, so I figure the same thing should work:

```
formset = QualsFormSet(instance = request.user, queryset=UserQualification.objects.filter(type__startswith='xyz'))
```

But going to this page just gives a TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'. There are two methods listed on that reference and I'm having trouble with both.

Answer (score 2):

I provided an answer to a slightly simpler version of this problem here:
[Limit Django's inlineformset_factory to only create new objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355532/limit-djangos-inlineformset-factory-to-only-create-new-objects/5154029#5154029)

For what you were trying to do, the InlineFormSet class would look like this instead:

```
class BaseInlineFilteredFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        ## See get_queryset method of django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet
        if not hasattr(self, '_queryset'):
            self._queryset = self.queryset.filter(type__startswith='xyz'))
            if not self._queryset.ordered:
                self._queryset = self._queryset.order_by(self.model._meta.pk.name)                
        return self._queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case you need to use the *form* parameter when calling inlineformset_factory and to pass it a custom form you made with an ad-hoc `__init__` method..
If you need it to be parametric, I found around here some time ago the life-saving line

```
    FormSetName.form = staticmethod(curry(FormName, customparam=chosenparam))
```

where, as explained above, FormSetName was defined with *form* parameter pointing to FormName.

Btw, would love to give credit to the person suggesting the above solution, would have loved to leave a heart-warming reply, but too little reputation.

### edit to explain better my solution:

This would be the custom *form* class (in this case, to chose a person as a *relative*, but only among a subset of people, those returned by the *relatives()* method):

```
class RelativeSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('relative',)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        profile = kwargs.pop('profile')
    except KeyError:
        super(RelativeSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return
    super(RelativeSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['relative'].queryset = profile.relatives().order_by('name')
```

and it would be used like so, in your *vies.py*:

```
RelativesFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Person, Person, form=RelativeSelectForm, can_delete=True, extra=1)
RelativesFormSet.form = staticmethod(curry(RelativeSelectForm, profile=request.user.profile))
```

so that every time you instantiate a formset it automatically gets the *profile* parameter filled with the right object and the queryset for the *relative* select box shows only people he has access to.
Hope I made myself a bit clearer :)

Comment: If I understand your idea, instead of creating a custom *form*, like you suggested, I should actually create a custom *formset*. Because in the formset init I could define a unique queryset. If this is the same idea you are referring to, this is the second method listed on that reference I included, but that doesn't seem to work for me. The only difference between me and that reference is i'm using inlineformset, not just modelformset. so I still don't get what I'm doing wrong? oh, and I don't think i need parametric, but thank you for the idea.

Comment: I actually meant, instead of manually choosing every field you are going to use, calling    FormSetName = inlineformset_factory(FirstModel, SecondModel, form=CustomForm, can_delete=True, extra=1) - you see, passing a Form class as a parameter to be used to instantiate every form.

Comment: oh i see your point. Unfortunately, I think we're talking about different things: I am having trouble with the records that are chosen in that formset, not the fields that are chosen. ie, User A opens the page with this formset and instead of seeing all of his qualifications (say a total of 5), he only sees some of them (maybe the first 3). The fields he sees for those qualifications are not the issue. I hope I clarified this?

Comment: I edited my solution, as I believe what I understood is what you need :)